# Hot to connect to remote MySQL server when my ISP is blocking 3306?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, connector

I am developing simple application with Visual Studio that gets data from remote MySQL server through MySql.Data.dll extension. Everything works fine when I'm in my own network, but when I'm at customer site it won't work. I'm assuming their IT is blocking port 3306. Since this is a big corp with strict rules cooperation with network admin is not an option. I heard about tunneling with SSH, tried to do some research but this time this is something not supported by my remote MySQL server provider. I'm out of ideas. What are my options?

Many thanks,
Paw

Comment: Web Services (rest, wcf)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip! Is it safe to pass queries from application to php?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command `> telnet <yourDBHost> 3306` to verify if port is blocked.
In that case, if you can't request to your admin to open port, maybe you can change the port of MySQL to another open port in the firewall, using your CPanel or editing config files directly if you can access it.